# Hiding standard report folders in sfdc

Tags: reporting

Is there any way by which report folders like the standard Lead reports, Sales Report, Campaign report can be hidden from reports for particular profiles?

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncheck couple of Administrative Permissions from the profile.

> 1. View Reports in Public Folders
> 2. View Dashboards in Public Folders

Comment: These two permissions are already unchecked!! any other workarounds?

Comment: @Sagnik Interesting! What folders that profile can see now ?

Comment: They can see all the standard folders like unfiled reports, sales, account reports and so on

Comment: You can't remove the access to Unfiled Reports Folder. Make sure other reports you have mentioned are not custom folders

Comment: yea that is what i was asking! is there any way we can remove access to standard folders ?